# Avoid switch case in Event Dispatcher to call corresponding Event Handler

Tags: c#, design-patterns, cqrs

We have more than 15 event handlers corresponding to each event type. I want to avoid below switch case in Event Dispatcher to call corresponding event handler based on the event type.

Here is my Event Dispatcher class:

```
public class EventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public EventDispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<ResultDto> HandleEvent(IEvent @event, ILogger logger)
        {
            ResultDto resultDto = null;
            switch (@event.EventType)
            {
                case EventType.CARD_BLOCK:
                    resultDto = await HandleAsync<CardBlockedEvent>(@event as CardBlockedEvent, logger);
                    break;
                case EventType.CARD_UNBLOCK:
                    resultDto = await HandleAsync<CardUnBlockedEvent>(@event as CardUnBlockedEvent, logger);
                    break;
                case EventType.CARD_CANCEL:
                    resultDto = await HandleAsync<CardCancelledEvent>(@event as CardCancelledEvent, logger);
                    break;
                case EventType.CARD_GROUP_CHANGED:
                    resultDto = await HandleAsync<CardGroupChangedEvent>(@event as CardGroupChangedEvent, logger);
                    break;
                case EventType.CARD_EXPIRY:
                    resultDto = await HandleAsync<CardExpiredEvent>(@event as CardExpiredEvent, logger);
                    break;
                default:
                    logger.Warning($"Unknown event type");
                    resultDto = new ResultDto { ResultType = ResultType.Failure, Message = "Unknown event type" };
                    break;
            }
            return resultDto;
        }
        private async Task<ResultDto> HandleAsync<TEvent>(TEvent @event, ILogger logger) where TEvent : IEvent
        {
            var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<ResultDto, TEvent>)) as IEventHandler<ResultDto, TEvent>;
            return await handler.HandleAsync(@event, logger);
        }

    }
```

Below is the Dependency Registrations:

```
 public class EventHandlerIoCRegistrations : IRegisterSevices
    {
        public void RegisterServicesWith(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            RegisterDispatcher(serviceCollection);
            RegisterHandlers(serviceCollection);
        }
        private void RegisterDispatcher(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IEventDispatcher, EventDispatcher>();
        }

        private void RegisterHandlers(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(item => item.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsGenericType).Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandler<,>)) && !item.IsAbstract && !item.IsInterface)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(assignedTypes =>
            {
                var serviceType = assignedTypes.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandler<,>));
                serviceCollection.AddScoped(serviceType, assignedTypes);

            });
        }
    }
```

Below is the Event handler interface:

```
public interface IEventHandler<TResult, TEvent>
        where TEvent : IEvent
        where TResult : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="event"></param>
        /// <param name="logger"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Task<TResult> HandleAsync(TEvent @event, ILogger logger);
    }
```

Is there any better way to do and to avoid this switch case?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to introduce some flavor of [polymophic statc binding](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2010/04/19/double-dispatch-is-a-code-smell/).

Consider

```
public interface IEvent {
  // ...
  
  // Here's the magic
  void HandleMe(IEventHandler target);
}

// Arbitrary examples
public class CardBlockedEvent : IEvent {
  // ...
  void HandleMe(IEventHandler target);
    target.HandleAsync<CardBlockedEvent>(this);
  }
}

public class CardUnBlockedEvent : IEvent {
  // ...
  void HandleMe(IEventHandler target);
    target.HandleAsync<CardUnBlockedEvent>(this);
  }
}
```

This introduces some coupling between `IEvent` and `IEventHandler`, in effect they are two participants (roles) in a single protocol.

Comment: Thanks! @VoiceOfUnreason for your suggestion